# How to do Load Testing using Soap UI for a specific Time and Specific Thread count

Tags: load, soapui, performance-testing, load-testing

I have to do load testing using `soapui` for 100 users within one hour and
calculate the `Transactions Per Second`.

I am using:
Threads: 10
Strategy:simple
Test delay: 1000
Random : 0.5
Limit: 10 Runs per thread

And in settings I have ticked "based on actual Time passed".

I am using runs per second, because then the count will be 100 (10 threads
* 10 runs per thread)

**Question1:** How can I make these users run for an hour?

**Question2:** Is the TPS visible in SoapUI correct? I mean when I have selected "actual Time passed" is TPS calculated with the waiting time? If so how can I get the TPS without waiting time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Re question 1.  Where you have defined 10 runs per thread, change the dropdown to seconds and update the limit for the number of seconds to run.

Comment: If I do that I cannot control my TPS . I want to keep my TPS at a certain leven as well